# Two columns in valueBox() in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want two columns in a valueBox(). One column will display description in row wise and other column will display values against the descriptions. 1st column should have values in text and second column values should be in numeric.

I tried using fluidrow() and with in 'fluidrow()' I build two columns.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  valueBox("Title",fluidRow(
      column(HTML("line1: <br> line2: <br> line3: "), status = "primary", 
title = "O",  width = 6 , 
      height = 120),
      column(HTML("100 <br> 200 <br> 300"), status = "primary", 
title = "B",  width = 6 , 
             height = 120)
))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: two columns]

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code already seems to be working, Could you please tell me what's the problem?

Comment: What about `"line1:&nbsp 100 <br> line2:&nbsp 200<br> line3:&nbsp 300"`. Please next time make sure to post working reproducible example.